# Why do I need a shell script to run a python script inside the container?

Tags: python, docker

Why does the first Dockerfile does not work? Meaning that it reports `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"python3 hello.py\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled`, where as the second Dockerfile works like a charm?

In other words, why do I need a shell script to run a python script inside the container?

Dockerfile 1:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY hello.py .
ENTRYPOINT [ "python hello.py" ]
```

Dockerfile 2:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY hello.py .
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENTRYPOINT` syntax requires either

- `ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "hello.py" ]` exec form, recommended
- `ENTRYPOINT python hello.py` shell form